# Knee wall insulation - Air gap behind drywall?

Tags: insulation

I'm doing some work in a knee wall space and am also planning to fix the ventilation and insulation. The primary fix is ventilation (or lack thereof) but there's some air infiltration in the insulation (or just poor insulation). In cold weather it is pretty clear with an IR camera.

On inspection, there's a couple of things I'm not sure about (see picture below):

1. The stud bays are empty and covered with cardboard sheets on the attic/unconditioned side. Insulation was added over the cardboard.

   - -> Do I need to keep this air space, or can/should I put the batts in the stud bay? I've [read a bit](https://joneakes.com/jons-fixit-database/2259-air-spaces-in-walls-myth-and-science---overview#a06Drywall) about it possibly being to prevent condensation, since the studs could have otherwise been a thermal bridge?
2. There's no blocking or top plate above the studs on the wall. Any "blocking" is dense packed fiberglass insulation.

   - -> This is probably tied to the air gap question... is this also needed?

I'm inclined to add R-21 batts to the stud bays, XPS strips over the studs, and cover the whole thing with EPS sheets (sealed with tape and/or spray foam). I assume if it is sealed properly, and those studs have enough insulation (let's say R-14... 1.5" XPS + 2" EPS) there shouldn't be any condensation issues?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The soffits are your air intake for the attic.  The soffits are in the knee wall section and provide the cool air that flows on the underside of the roof sheathing and exits - hopefully - from a ridge vent.  If you block this flow you get various issues.  Baffles are used to preserve the flow of air and you can insulate up to them.  What kind of shingles do you have, asphalt?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should add some highlighting or clearer description. The cardboard baffles I'm referring to are on the studs and stops a little before the top. Currently, the air flow out the knee wall is  _mostly_ blocked over the slanted part of the ceiling (packed with fiberglass). I'm planning to fix this by pushing up some plastic baffles, but wasn't sure what to do with the cardboard on the wall. It doesn't appear to be for anything related to the overall ventilation of the knee wall.
And yes, asphalt shingles. Which is part of the reason for fixing that ventilation from the knee wall.

Comment: got it.  your plan looks good.  I'd get rid of the knee wall cardboard.  I like drying potential to outside though so not sure i'd go foil faced EPS...  I'd probably do SIGA Majrex as the airbarrier and use a vb paint on the interior surface of the drywall as vb and avoid the foil faced insulation.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger thank you. I was thinking the EPS would act as an air barrier, even without the foil. It looks like that is not correct, so the SIGA Majrex would do that for me?

Comment: yeah the intelligent air barriers provide air barrier but with vapor permeability unlike poly or foil.